# Python - Unsupported Operand Type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python

So I'm working on a little Roulette program, and when I try to take/add to the users balance, it comes up with the error that has been titled, what makes the program do this and how do I fix it?

```
import random
import time

balance = 100

outcome = random.randint(0,17)
if outcome == 0:
    color = "GREEN"
elif outcome <=7:
    color = "RED"
else:
    color = "BLACK"

print("Current Balance: $"+str(balance))
colorChoice = input("Place your bet by typing either: RED, GREEN or BLACK\n")
colorChoice = colorChoice.upper()
betAmount = input("How much would you like to bet?\n")
if int(betAmount) > balance:
    print("Insufficient Funds")
else:
    print("** ROLLING **")
    time.sleep(2.5)
    print("The color landed on: " + color)
    if colorChoice == color and color == "GREEN":
        print("Win! Your balance has been adjusted!\nYou selected: " +     colorChoice + " and the spinner landed on: " + color)
        greenLand = betAmount * 14
        balance = balance + greenLand
    elif colorChoice == color and color == "RED":
        print("Win! Your balance has been adjusted!\nYou selected: " + colorChoice + " and the spinner landed on: " + color)
        balance = balance + betAmount
    elif colorChoice == color and color == "BLACK":
        print("Win! Your balance has been adjusted!\nYou selected: " + colorChoice + " and the spinner landed on: " + color)
        balance = balance + betAmount
    elif colorChoice != color and color == "GREEN":
        print("Loss! Your balance has been adjusted!\nYou selected: " + colorChoice + " and the spinner landed on: " + color)
        balance = balance - betAmount        
    elif colorChoice != color and color == "RED":
        print("Loss! Your balance has been adjusted!\nYou selected: " + colorChoice + " and the spinner landed on: " + color)
        balance = balance - betAmount        
    elif colorChoice != color and color == "BLACK":
        print("Loss! Your balance has been adjusted!\nYou selected: " + colorChoice + " and the spinner landed on: " + color)
        balance = balance - betAmount        
    print("New Balance: $" + str(balance))
```

Just so this post doesn't get down-voted, I would like to re-iterate that my issue is occuring when I try to manipulate the balance variable in the if/elif statements at the bottom!

Comment: Your `betAmount` variable is a string, and your `balance` is an integer. Obviously, you can't subtract an integer from a string. Convert `betAmount` to an integer, like you did in `int(betAmount) > balance`. Note that `int()` calls don't change the type of their argument everywhere in your code, just in the place you called it in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your betAmount should be declared as `int(input("How much would you like to bet?\n"))` to make it an integer. And as commented, to make integer match with integer. Arithmetically.